# Simple harmonic motion in a non-inertial frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

For **simple harmonic motion** in a non-inertial frame is amplitude same on both sides? As in one direction pseudo force supports acceleration due to spring and in another direction it opposes acceleration due to spring. So how will it affect the amplitude of this motion?

Comment: Amplitude never changes in shm. Do you mean to ask whether amplitude will change in non inertial frame? If so, then no it'll also remain same just like it is for shm in inertial frame.

Comment: so can you please plot the graph for shm in  a non inertial frame and can you please explain how amplitude remains same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the pseudoforce be $f$. Then the equation of motion in the non inertial frame is
$$m \ddot{x} = -kx + f = -k\left(x - \frac{f}{k}\right)$$
Change variables to $X =x - \frac{f}{k}$, then the equation of motion is
$$m\ddot{X} = -kX$$
which is the equation for shm with solution
$$X = A \cos (\omega t + \phi)$$
where $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$ and $A$ is the amplitude of the motion. Substituting back you get
$$x = A \cos(\omega t + \phi) + \frac{f}{k}$$
The motion is still simple harmonic, the amplitude remains the same throughout the motion but the centre of oscillation (equilibrium position) is shifted by an amount $\frac{f}{k}$

Comment: yes the mean position will shift.Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are in euclidean space and so placing yourself in a non-inertial frame corresponds to apply a global transformation, in the sense that every point of space has associated this acceleration vector that corresponds to the opposite of your acceleration seen from an inertial frame of reference.

Consider first the case in which you have an horizontal spring with a mass inside your car; what would happen if you accelerate? the fulcrum to which the spring is attached will follow car's movement but the mass want to persist in its inertia and the spring will be tensed in a direction opposite to the acceleration; there will be no oscillation if you can ideally put a constant acceleration in your car. Precisely the spring will be tensed so that $kx=ma$.

This is like a "point zero" displacement, the displacement of your spring due just to external acceleration, without obscillation. *But* in this case the force exterted to the mass pass through the spring by the fulcrum.

*Instead* when you change frame of refernce it's like an "invisible force" is acting on both the fulcrum and the mass, so the force exterted by the fulcrum through the spring is not present.

In fact there is no "point zero displacement"; if your mass on the spring is at rest, it will remain like this even if you see it *outside* your car while you're passing it, accelerating.

The amplitude of your armonic motion will be intact.

Comment: I didn't get it may be i need to study more :-D .THANK YOU for your answer.